# Class Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When i am trying to persist content through my entity i get the following error:

> Class `Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation` is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

I have done some research, but can't find anything that solves this problem.

The error disappears when I change:

```
orm: 
    default: translatable: true
```

To:

```
 orm: default: ~
```

in `config.yml`.

But the content is not saved as translation, but overwrites the existing content in the "new" language.

I have the following relevant lines in my deps file:

```
[symfony]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=origin/2.0

[gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
   git=http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git
   version=v2.3.0

[Stof-DoctrineExtensionsBundle]
   git=https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
   target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are requesting version 2.3.0 of the extensions but your symfony version is 2.0.x which does not include the latest Doctrine version. You should change this to:

```
[gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git
    version=v2.1.0

[DoctrineExtensionsBundle]
    git=http://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
    version=1.0.0
```